# How ssh to a virtualbox with static ip (192.168.1.111) from linux host machine with no wifi/ethernet?

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, ssh, virtualbox

When there is no wifi connection or ethernet connection, I'm unable to reach the OS in VirtualBox from the same machine (i.e. the host OS). From reading this post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/247625/what-is-the-loopback-device-and-how-do-i-use-it this is because:

> When a network interface is disconnected--for example, when an Ethernet port is unplugged or Wi-Fi is turned off or not associated with an access point--no communication on that interface is possible, not even communication between your computer and itself.

That answer recommends using the "loopback device" instead, but loopback is `127.0.0.0/8` and my VirtualBox OS is set to a static ip of 192.168.1.111 (and I don't want to have to change this). How do I make it reachable?

SETUP:

```
* Host Machine (Laptop): openSUSE 13.1
    * VirtualBox: CentOS 6 (192.168.1.111)
```

I want to ssh from openSUSE to CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the question I answered for someone else with a Windows VirtualBox host and a linux guest yesterday.

[CentOs localhost only work when connected to internet](https://superuser.com/questions/726371/centos-localhost-only-work-when-connected-to-internet/726377#726377)

If you can adapt the instructions for Linux, then follow the bit under "Edit: New suggested configuration" to create an always-available network for your Linux host to talk to your VirtualBox guest using VirtualBox's "Host-Only network adapter", and then a second network connection bridged to your WiFi connection so the Virtual Machine can get out to the internet.

I'm not sure if you can get away without changing the guest's IP address though.

Comment: I will take a look but I need the static IP so other computers on the network can reach it when it's back online.

Answer (score 0):

here is suse ics info
https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Internet_connection_sharing
and setup static ips between guest vm and host machine